# SlideShow HTML Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, slide

Baixei um pacote para slideshow o qual eu inclui no meu site porem ele esta todo desconfigurado, não aparece borda e não aparece as imagens dos botoes, estou tentando concertar esse erro ha no minimo 6 horas, os scripts são os seguintes

Pagina index:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Code Programming</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS -->
  <style type="text/css">
  @import "css/layout.css";
  </style>
  
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css"/>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#coin-slider').coinslider();
});
  </script>
  
  
</head>
  <body>
<div id="container">

    <?php
      include "includes/menucabecalho.html";
      ?>

      <div id='coin-slider'>
  <a href="img01_url" target="_blank">
<img src='img01.jpg' >
<span>
  Description for img01
</span>
  </a>
  ......
  ......
  <a href="imgN_url">
<img src='imgN.jpg' >
<span>
  Description for imgN
</span>
  </a>
</div>


      <?php
      include "includes/footer.html";
      ?>

</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Arquivo coin-slider.js

```js
/**
 * Coin Slider - Unique jQuery Image Slider
 * @version: 1.0 - (2010/04/04)
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.2 or later 
 * @author Ivan Lazarevic
 * Examples and documentation at: http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/
 
 * Licensed under MIT licence:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
**/

(function($) {

    var params      = new Array;
    var order       = new Array;
    var images      = new Array;
    var links       = new Array;
    var linksTarget = new Array;
    var titles      = new Array;
    var interval    = new Array;
    var imagePos    = new Array;
    var appInterval = new Array;    
    var squarePos   = new Array;    
    var reverse     = new Array;
    
    $.fn.coinslider= $.fn.CoinSlider = function(options){
        
        init = function(el){
                
            order[el.id]        = new Array();  // order of square appereance
            images[el.id]       = new Array();
            links[el.id]        = new Array();
            linksTarget[el.id]  = new Array();
            titles[el.id]       = new Array();
            imagePos[el.id]     = 0;
            squarePos[el.id]    = 0;
            reverse[el.id]      = 1;                        
                
            params[el.id] = $.extend({}, $.fn.coinslider.defaults, options);
                        
            // create images, links and titles arrays
            $.each($('#'+el.id+' img'), function(i,item){
                images[el.id][i]        = $(item).attr('src');
                links[el.id][i]         = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('href') : '';
                linksTarget[el.id][i]   = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('target') : '';
                titles[el.id][i]        = $(item).next().is('span') ? $(item).next().html() : '';
                $(item).hide();
                $(item).next().hide();
            });         
            

            // set panel
            $(el).css({
                'background-image':'url('+images[el.id][0]+')',
                'width': params[el.id].width,
                'height': params[el.id].height,
                'position': 'relative',
                'background-position': 'top left'
            }).wrap("<div class='coin-slider' id='coin-slider-"+el.id+"' />");  
            
                
            // create title bar
            $('#'+el.id).append("<div class='cs-title' id='cs-title-"+el.id+"' style='position: absolute; bottom:0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;'></div>");
                        
            $.setFields(el);
            
            if(params[el.id].navigation)
                $.setNavigation(el);
            
            $.transition(el,0);
            $.transitionCall(el);
                
        }
        
        // squares positions
        $.setFields = function(el){
            
            tWidth = sWidth = parseInt(params[el.id].width/params[el.id].spw);
            tHeight = sHeight = parseInt(params[el.id].height/params[el.id].sph);
            
            counter = sLeft = sTop = 0;
            tgapx = gapx = params[el.id].width - params[el.id].spw*sWidth;
            tgapy = gapy = params[el.id].height - params[el.id].sph*sHeight;
            
            for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
                gapx = tgapx;
                
                    if(gapy > 0){
                        gapy--;
                        sHeight = tHeight+1;
                    } else {
                        sHeight = tHeight;
                    }
                
                for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){  

                    if(gapx > 0){
                        gapx--;
                        sWidth = tWidth+1;
                    } else {
                        sWidth = tWidth;
                    }

                    order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
                    counter++;
                    
                    if(params[el.id].links)
                        $('#'+el.id).append("<a href='"+links[el.id][0]+"' class='cs-"+el.id+"' id='cs-"+el.id+i+j+"' style='width:"+sWidth+"px; height:"+sHeight+"px; float: left; position: absolute;'></a>");
                    else
                        $('#'+el.id).append("<div class='cs-"+el.id+"' id='cs-"+el.id+i+j+"' style='width:"+sWidth+"px; height:"+sHeight+"px; float: left; position: absolute;'></div>");
                                
                    // positioning squares
                    $("#cs-"+el.id+i+j).css({ 
                        'background-position': -sLeft +'px '+(-sTop+'px'),
                        'left' : sLeft ,
                        'top': sTop
                    });
                
                    sLeft += sWidth;
                }

                sTop += sHeight;
                sLeft = 0;                  
                    
            }
            
            
            $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
                $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show();
            });
        
            $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
                $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
            }); 
            
            $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
                $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show();
            });
        
            $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
                $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
            }); 
            
            if(params[el.id].hoverPause){   
                $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
                    params[el.id].pause = true;
                });
            
                $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
                    params[el.id].pause = false;
                }); 
                
                $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
                    params[el.id].pause = true;
                });
            
                $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
                    params[el.id].pause = false;
                }); 
            }
                    
            
        };
                
        
        $.transitionCall = function(el){
        
            clearInterval(interval[el.id]); 
            delay = params[el.id].delay + params[el.id].spw*params[el.id].sph*params[el.id].sDelay;
            interval[el.id] = setInterval(function() { $.transition(el)  }, delay);
            
        }
        
        // transitions
        $.transition = function(el,direction){
            
            if(params[el.id].pause == true) return;
            
            $.effect(el);
            
            squarePos[el.id] = 0;
            appInterval[el.id] = setInterval(function() { $.appereance(el,order[el.id][squarePos[el.id]])  },params[el.id].sDelay);
                    
            $(el).css({ 'background-image': 'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')' });
            
            if(typeof(direction) == "undefined")
                imagePos[el.id]++;
            else
                if(direction == 'prev')
                    imagePos[el.id]--;
                else
                    imagePos[el.id] = direction;
        
            if  (imagePos[el.id] == images[el.id].length) {
                imagePos[el.id] = 0;
            }
            
            if (imagePos[el.id] == -1){
                imagePos[el.id] = images[el.id].length-1;
            }
    
            $('.cs-button-'+el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
            $('#cs-button-'+el.id+"-"+(imagePos[el.id]+1)).addClass('cs-active');
            
            if(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]){
                $('#cs-title-'+el.id).css({ 'opacity' : 0 }).animate({ 'opacity' : params[el.id].opacity }, params[el.id].titleSpeed);
                $('#cs-title-'+el.id).html(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);
            } else {
                $('#cs-title-'+el.id).css('opacity',0);
            }               
                
        };
        
        $.appereance = function(el,sid){

            $('.cs-'+el.id).attr('href',links[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]).attr('target',linksTarget[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);

            if (squarePos[el.id] == params[el.id].spw*params[el.id].sph) {
                clearInterval(appInterval[el.id]);
                return;
            }

            $('#cs-'+el.id+sid).css({ opacity: 0, 'background-image': 'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')' });
            $('#cs-'+el.id+sid).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
            squarePos[el.id]++;
            
        };
        
        // navigation
        $.setNavigation = function(el){
            // create prev and next 
            $(el).append("<div id='cs-navigation-"+el.id+"'></div>");
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
            
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-prev-"+el.id+"' class='cs-prev'>prev</a>");
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-next-"+el.id+"' class='cs-next'>next</a>");
            $('#cs-prev-'+el.id).css({
                'position'  : 'absolute',
                'top'       : params[el.id].height/2 - 15,
                'left'      : 0,
                'z-index'   : 1001,
                'line-height': '30px',
                'opacity'   : params[el.id].opacity
            }).click( function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.transition(el,'prev');
                $.transitionCall(el);       
            }).mouseover( function(){ $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show() });
    
            $('#cs-next-'+el.id).css({
                'position'  : 'absolute',
                'top'       : params[el.id].height/2 - 15,
                'right'     : 0,
                'z-index'   : 1001,
                'line-height': '30px',
                'opacity'   : params[el.id].opacity
            }).click( function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.transition(el);
                $.transitionCall(el);
            }).mouseover( function(){ $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show() });
        
            // image buttons
            $("<div id='cs-buttons-"+el.id+"' class='cs-buttons'></div>").appendTo($('#coin-slider-'+el.id));

            
            for(k=1;k<images[el.id].length+1;k++){
                $('#cs-buttons-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' class='cs-button-"+el.id+"' id='cs-button-"+el.id+"-"+k+"'>"+k+"</a>");
            }
            
            $.each($('.cs-button-'+el.id), function(i,item){
                $(item).click( function(e){
                    $('.cs-button-'+el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
                    $(this).addClass('cs-active');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.transition(el,i);
                    $.transitionCall(el);               
                })
            }); 
            
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id+' a').mouseout(function(){
                $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
                params[el.id].pause = false;
            });                     

            $("#cs-buttons-"+el.id).css({
                'left'          : '50%',
                'margin-left'   : -images[el.id].length*15/2-5,
                'position'      : 'relative'
                
            });
            
                
        }




        // effects
        $.effect = function(el){
            
            effA = ['random','swirl','rain','straight'];
            if(params[el.id].effect == '')
                eff = effA[Math.floor(Math.random()*(effA.length))];
            else
                eff = params[el.id].effect;

            order[el.id] = new Array();

            if(eff == 'random'){
                counter = 0;
                  for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
                    for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){  
                        order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
                        counter++;
                    }
                  } 
                $.random(order[el.id]);
            }
            
            if(eff == 'rain')   {
                $.rain(el);
            }
            
            if(eff == 'swirl')
                $.swirl(el);
                
            if(eff == 'straight')
                $.straight(el);
                
            reverse[el.id] *= -1;
            if(reverse[el.id] > 0){
                order[el.id].reverse();
            }

        }

            
        // shuffle array function
        $.random = function(arr) {
                        
          var i = arr.length;
          if ( i == 0 ) return false;
          while ( --i ) {
             var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
             var tempi = arr[i];
             var tempj = arr[j];
             arr[i] = tempj;
             arr[j] = tempi;
           }
        }   
        
        //swirl effect by milos popovic
        $.swirl = function(el){

            var n = params[el.id].sph;
            var m = params[el.id].spw;

            var x = 1;
            var y = 1;
            var going = 0;
            var num = 0;
            var c = 0;
            
            var dowhile = true;
                        
            while(dowhile) {
                
                num = (going==0 || going==2) ? m : n;
                
                for (i=1;i<=num;i++){
                    
                    order[el.id][c] = x+''+y;
                    c++;

                    if(i!=num){
                        switch(going){
                            case 0 : y++; break;
                            case 1 : x++; break;
                            case 2 : y--; break;
                            case 3 : x--; break;
                        
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                going = (going+1)%4;

                switch(going){
                    case 0 : m--; y++; break;
                    case 1 : n--; x++; break;
                    case 2 : m--; y--; break;
                    case 3 : n--; x--; break;       
                }
                
                check = $.max(n,m) - $.min(n,m);            
                if(m<=check && n<=check)
                    dowhile = false;
                                    
            }
        }

        // rain effect
        $.rain = function(el){
            var n = params[el.id].sph;
            var m = params[el.id].spw;

            var c = 0;
            var to = to2 = from = 1;
            var dowhile = true;


            while(dowhile){
                
                for(i=from;i<=to;i++){
                    order[el.id][c] = i+''+parseInt(to2-i+1);
                    c++;
                }
                
                to2++;
                
                if(to < n && to2 < m && n<m){
                    to++;   
                }
                
                if(to < n && n>=m){
                    to++;   
                }
                
                if(to2 > m){
                    from++;
                }
                
                if(from > to) dowhile= false;
                
            }           

        }

        // straight effect
        $.straight = function(el){
            counter = 0;
            for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
                for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){  
                    order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
                    counter++;
                }
                
            }
        }

        $.min = function(n,m){
            if (n>m) return m;
            else return n;
        }
        
        $.max = function(n,m){
            if (n<m) return m;
            else return n;
        }       
    
    this.each (
        function(){ init(this); }
    );
    

    };
    
    
    // default values
    $.fn.coinslider.defaults = {    
        width: 565, // width of slider panel
        height: 290, // height of slider panel
        spw: 7, // squares per width
        sph: 5, // squares per height
        delay: 3000, // delay between images in ms
        sDelay: 30, // delay beetwen squares in ms
        opacity: 0.7, // opacity of title and navigation
        titleSpeed: 500, // speed of title appereance in ms
        effect: '', // random, swirl, rain, straight
        navigation: true, // prev next and buttons
        links : true, // show images as links 
        hoverPause: true // pause on hover      
    };  
    
})(jQuery);
```

Arquivo coin-slider.min:

```js
/**
 * Coin Slider - Unique jQuery Image Slider
 * @version: 1.0 - (2010/04/04)
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.2 or later
 * @author Ivan Lazarevic
 * Examples and documentation at: http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/

 * Licensed under MIT licence:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
**/

(function($){var params=new Array;var order=new Array;var images=new Array;var links=new Array;var linksTarget=new Array;var titles=new Array;var interval=new Array;var imagePos=new Array;var appInterval=new Array;var squarePos=new Array;var reverse=new Array;$.fn.coinslider=$.fn.CoinSlider=function(options){init=function(el){order[el.id]=new Array();images[el.id]=new Array();links[el.id]=new Array();linksTarget[el.id]=new Array();titles[el.id]=new Array();imagePos[el.id]=0;squarePos[el.id]=0;reverse[el.id]=1;params[el.id]=$.extend({},$.fn.coinslider.defaults,options);$.each($('#'+el.id+' img'),function(i,item){images[el.id][i]=$(item).attr('src');links[el.id][i]=$(item).parent().is('a')?$(item).parent().attr('href'):'';linksTarget[el.id][i]=$(item).parent().is('a')?$(item).parent().attr('target'):'';titles[el.id][i]=$(item).next().is('span')?$(item).next().html():'';$(item).hide();$(item).next().hide();});$(el).css({'background-image':'url('+images[el.id][0]+')','width':params[el.id].width,'height':params[el.id].height,'position':'relative','background-position':'top left'}).wrap("<div class='coin-slider' id='coin-slider-"+el.id+"' />");$('#'+el.id).append("<div class='cs-title' id='cs-title-"+el.id+"' style='position: absolute; bottom:0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;'></div>");$.setFields(el);if(params[el.id].navigation)
$.setNavigation(el);$.transition(el,0);$.transitionCall(el);}
$.setFields=function(el){tWidth=sWidth=parseInt(params[el.id].width/params[el.id].spw);tHeight=sHeight=parseInt(params[el.id].height/params[el.id].sph);counter=sLeft=sTop=0;tgapx=gapx=params[el.id].width-params[el.id].spw*sWidth;tgapy=gapy=params[el.id].height-params[el.id].sph*sHeight;for(i=1;i<=params[el.id].sph;i++){gapx=tgapx;if(gapy>0){gapy--;sHeight=tHeight+1;}else{sHeight=tHeight;}
for(j=1;j<=params[el.id].spw;j++){if(gapx>0){gapx--;sWidth=tWidth+1;}else{sWidth=tWidth;}
order[el.id][counter]=i+''+j;counter++;if(params[el.id].links)
$('#'+el.id).append("<a href='"+links[el.id][0]+"' class='cs-"+el.id+"' id='cs-"+el.id+i+j+"' style='width:"+sWidth+"px; height:"+sHeight+"px; float: left; position: absolute;'></a>");else
$('#'+el.id).append("<div class='cs-"+el.id+"' id='cs-"+el.id+i+j+"' style='width:"+sWidth+"px; height:"+sHeight+"px; float: left; position: absolute;'></div>");$("#cs-"+el.id+i+j).css({'background-position':-sLeft+'px '+(-sTop+'px'),'left':sLeft,'top':sTop});sLeft+=sWidth;}
sTop+=sHeight;sLeft=0;}
$('.cs-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show();});$('.cs-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();});$('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show();});$('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();});if(params[el.id].hoverPause){$('.cs-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){params[el.id].pause=true;});$('.cs-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){params[el.id].pause=false;});$('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){params[el.id].pause=true;});$('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){params[el.id].pause=false;});}};$.transitionCall=function(el){clearInterval(interval[el.id]);delay=params[el.id].delay+params[el.id].spw*params[el.id].sph*params[el.id].sDelay;interval[el.id]=setInterval(function(){$.transition(el)},delay);}
$.transition=function(el,direction){if(params[el.id].pause==true)return;$.effect(el);squarePos[el.id]=0;appInterval[el.id]=setInterval(function(){$.appereance(el,order[el.id][squarePos[el.id]])},params[el.id].sDelay);$(el).css({'background-image':'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')'});if(typeof(direction)=="undefined")
imagePos[el.id]++;else
if(direction=='prev')
imagePos[el.id]--;else
imagePos[el.id]=direction;if(imagePos[el.id]==images[el.id].length){imagePos[el.id]=0;}
if(imagePos[el.id]==-1){imagePos[el.id]=images[el.id].length-1;}
$('.cs-button-'+el.id).removeClass('cs-active');$('#cs-button-'+el.id+"-"+(imagePos[el.id]+1)).addClass('cs-active');if(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]){$('#cs-title-'+el.id).css({'opacity':0}).animate({'opacity':params[el.id].opacity},params[el.id].titleSpeed);$('#cs-title-'+el.id).html(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);}else{$('#cs-title-'+el.id).css('opacity',0);}};$.appereance=function(el,sid){$('.cs-'+el.id).attr('href',links[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]).attr('target',linksTarget[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);if(squarePos[el.id]==params[el.id].spw*params[el.id].sph){clearInterval(appInterval[el.id]);return;}
$('#cs-'+el.id+sid).css({opacity:0,'background-image':'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')'});$('#cs-'+el.id+sid).animate({opacity:1},300);squarePos[el.id]++;};$.setNavigation=function(el){$(el).append("<div id='cs-navigation-"+el.id+"'></div>");$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-prev-"+el.id+"' class='cs-prev'>prev</a>");$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-next-"+el.id+"' class='cs-next'>next</a>");$('#cs-prev-'+el.id).css({'position':'absolute','top':params[el.id].height/2-15,'left':0,'z-index':1001,'line-height':'30px','opacity':params[el.id].opacity}).click(function(e){e.preventDefault();$.transition(el,'prev');$.transitionCall(el);}).mouseover(function(){$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show()});$('#cs-next-'+el.id).css({'position':'absolute','top':params[el.id].height/2-15,'right':0,'z-index':1001,'line-height':'30px','opacity':params[el.id].opacity}).click(function(e){e.preventDefault();$.transition(el);$.transitionCall(el);}).mouseover(function(){$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show()});$("<div id='cs-buttons-"+el.id+"' class='cs-buttons'></div>").appendTo($('#coin-slider-'+el.id));for(k=1;k<images[el.id].length+1;k++){$('#cs-buttons-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' class='cs-button-"+el.id+"' id='cs-button-"+el.id+"-"+k+"'>"+k+"</a>");}
$.each($('.cs-button-'+el.id),function(i,item){$(item).click(function(e){$('.cs-button-'+el.id).removeClass('cs-active');$(this).addClass('cs-active');e.preventDefault();$.transition(el,i);$.transitionCall(el);})});$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id+' a').mouseout(function(){$('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();params[el.id].pause=false;});$("#cs-buttons-"+el.id).css({'left':'50%','margin-left':-images[el.id].length*15/2-5,'position':'relative'});}
$.effect=function(el){effA=['random','swirl','rain','straight'];if(params[el.id].effect=='')
eff=effA[Math.floor(Math.random()*(effA.length))];else
eff=params[el.id].effect;order[el.id]=new Array();if(eff=='random'){counter=0;for(i=1;i<=params[el.id].sph;i++){for(j=1;j<=params[el.id].spw;j++){order[el.id][counter]=i+''+j;counter++;}}
$.random(order[el.id]);}
if(eff=='rain'){$.rain(el);}
if(eff=='swirl')
$.swirl(el);if(eff=='straight')
$.straight(el);reverse[el.id]*=-1;if(reverse[el.id]>0){order[el.id].reverse();}}
$.random=function(arr){var i=arr.length;if(i==0)return false;while(--i){var j=Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));var tempi=arr[i];var tempj=arr[j];arr[i]=tempj;arr[j]=tempi;}}
$.swirl=function(el){var n=params[el.id].sph;var m=params[el.id].spw;var x=1;var y=1;var going=0;var num=0;var c=0;var dowhile=true;while(dowhile){num=(going==0||going==2)?m:n;for(i=1;i<=num;i++){order[el.id][c]=x+''+y;c++;if(i!=num){switch(going){case 0:y++;break;case 1:x++;break;case 2:y--;break;case 3:x--;break;}}}
going=(going+1)%4;switch(going){case 0:m--;y++;break;case 1:n--;x++;break;case 2:m--;y--;break;case 3:n--;x--;break;}
check=$.max(n,m)-$.min(n,m);if(m<=check&&n<=check)
dowhile=false;}}
$.rain=function(el){var n=params[el.id].sph;var m=params[el.id].spw;var c=0;var to=to2=from=1;var dowhile=true;while(dowhile){for(i=from;i<=to;i++){order[el.id][c]=i+''+parseInt(to2-i+1);c++;}
to2++;if(to<n&&to2<m&&n<m){to++;}
if(to<n&&n>=m){to++;}
if(to2>m){from++;}
if(from>to)dowhile=false;}}
$.straight=function(el){counter=0;for(i=1;i<=params[el.id].sph;i++){for(j=1;j<=params[el.id].spw;j++){order[el.id][counter]=i+''+j;counter++;}}}
$.min=function(n,m){if(n>m)return m;else return n;}
$.max=function(n,m){if(n<m)return m;else return n;}
this.each(function(){init(this);});};$.fn.coinslider.defaults={width:565,height:290,spw:7,sph:5,delay:3000,sDelay:30,opacity:0.7,titleSpeed:500,effect:'',navigation:true,links:true,hoverPause:true};})(jQuery);


$('#coin-slider').coinslider();
```

Arquivo coin-slider-style:

```css
.coin-slider { overflow: hidden; zoom: 1; position: relative; }
.coin-slider a{ text-decoration: none; outline: none; border: none; }

.cs-buttons { font-size: 0px; padding: 10px; float: left; }
.cs-buttons a { margin-left: 5px; height: 10px; width: 10px; float: left; border: 1px solid #B8C4CF; color: #B8C4CF; text-indent: -1000px; }
.cs-active { background-color: #B8C4CF; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-title { width: 545px; padding: 10px; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-prev, 
.cs-next { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 0px 10px; }
```

Imagem do site [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo HTML DA PAGINA:

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0033)http://127.0.0.1/CodeProgramming/ -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Code Programming</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS -->
  <style type="text/css">
  @import "css/layout.css";
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Code Programming2_files/coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./Code Programming2_files/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#coin-slider').coinslider();
});
  </script>
  <script src="./Code Programming2_files/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
<div id="container">

    

        <header>
            <h1>Code Programming</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="">Principal</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Faculdade</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Outros</a></li>
            </ol>
        </nav>


      <div id="coin-slider">
  <a href="http://127.0.0.1/CodeProgramming/img01_url" target="_blank">
<img src="./Code Programming2_files/img01.jpg">
<span>
  Description for img01
</span>
  </a>
  ......
  ......
  <a href="http://127.0.0.1/CodeProgramming/imgN_url">
<img src="./Code Programming2_files/imgN.jpg">
<span>
  Description for imgN
</span>
  </a>
</div>


      




    <footer></footer>



</div>

 

</body></html>
```

[image: NOVOS ERROS ENCONTRADOS]

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML renderizado? ou seja como aparece no browser

Comment: como faz isso amigo?

Comment: Abre a página no browser e grava. Depois abre com um editor e coloca aqui.

Comment: Não sei fazer isso sergio, vou postar a imagem de como estar tudo bem?

Comment: Rafael, se não sabes como gravar uma página HTML e copiar o HTML dela acho que este problema é demasiado complexo para o conhecimento que tens atualmente. Acho que deves começar por algo mais simples.

Comment: O html é o primeiro script Sergio... acho que sua explicação que é sucinta.

Comment: Rafael, no primeiro pedaço de código tens código PHP misturado. Esse PHP é script que corre no servidor e vai gerar ainda mais HTML. Ou seja, esta linha `include "includes/menucabecalho.html";` vai gerar uma série de HTML. Para perceber qual pode ser o teu problema quero ver o HTML completo. Pode ser que haja uma `<div>` que está mal fechada no cabeçalho ou footer e isso está a baralhar o CSS/JS. Quando o servidor envia essa página para o browser aí então a página está completa. É esse HTML que eu quero ver, o que está no Browser.

Comment: Acho que entendi oque voce esta solicitando, da uma olhada no ultimo bloco inserido.

Comment: Falta um `>` no final de `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css" /`. Se faltar mesmo, pode ser só isso (não carregou os estilos do slider).

Comment: Adicionei o /> e não funcionou

Comment: @Rafael2F boa! era isso que queria. Dá uma olhada na consola, e diz se há algum erro. Corrige também o que o bfavaretto referiu e repara que tens espacos em branco nos path aqui `/Code Programming_files/`. Não sei se isso não vai dar asneira.

Comment: @Rafael2F estás a juntar ambos o `coin-slider.min.js` e o `coin-slider.js`??

Comment: @Sergio o codigo original do caminho que voce esta se referindo é esse <script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script> ou seja, não tem espaço. Vou colar o print dos erros em console.

Comment: E estás a juntar só o minificado ou o não monificado/comprimido também? Estás a iniciar o slider? (com `$('#coin-slider').coinslider();`)

Comment: Eu não sei Sergio, estou usando os codigo JQuery e Javascript da net, ainda não comecei a estudar essas linguagens.

Comment: Ok, resposta dada. Testa e pergunta aqui se não conseguires sozinho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que esqueceste de 2 coisas:

Carregar o jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

e iniciar o slider com `$('#coin-slider').coinslider();`

Depois de carregares o CSS, o JS e o HTML estar no lugar tens de chamar/iniciar o slider. Para isso selecionas o elemento que contém o HTML do slider e chamas o método do plugin.

Se colocares no final da página antes do `</body>` podes usar assim:

```
<script>
$('#coin-slider').coinslider();
</script>
```

Se quiseres carregar no head ou inicio do body podes usar assim:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#coin-slider').coinslider();
});
</script>
```

Usando o teu código era só isso que faltava: https://jsfiddle.net/tjqjoLuc/